# How to convert numbers to strings?

Tags: c++, math, c++14, visual-studio-2022

I need to convert numbers between 0 and 1 billion to German words as a wstring.

I was pretty sure I got it right, but somewhere I have a mistake, and I don't see which.

For example for 1001, it should say "eintausendeins" ("onethousandone"), but instead it returns "nulleins" ("zero one").

Where am I going wrong?

```
wstring NumberToWords(wstring u) 
{
    map<int, wstring> numberWords = 
    {
      {0, L"null"},
      {1, L"eins"},
      {2, L"zwei"},
      {3, L"drei"},
      {4, L"vier"},
      {5, L"fünf"},
      {6, L"sechs"},
      {7, L"sieben"},
      {8, L"acht"},
      {9, L"neun"},
      {10, L"zehn"},
      {11, L"elf"},
      {12, L"zwölf"},
      {13, L"dreizehn"},
      {14, L"vierzehn"},
      {15, L"fünfzehn"},
      {16, L"sechzehn"},
      {17, L"siebzehn"},
      {18, L"achtzehn"},
      {19, L"neunzehn"},
      {20, L"zwanzig"},
      {30, L"dreißig"},
      {40, L"vierzig"},
      {50, L"fünfzig"},
      {60, L"sechzig"},
      {70, L"siebzig"},
      {80, L"achtzig"},
      {90, L"neunzig"},
      {100, L"hundert"},
      {1000, L"tausend"},
      {1000000, L"million"},
      {1000000000, L"milliarde"}
    };

    std::wstring result = L"";
    std::wstring number = u;
    if (number.empty() || number == L"0") 
    {
        return numberWords[0];
    }

    std::vector<int> numberParts;
    int size = number.size();
    int start = size - 3;
    int end = size;
    while (start >= 0) 
    {
        if (start == 0 && size % 3 != 0) 
        {
            numberParts.push_back(stoi(number.substr(0, end - start)));
            break;
        }
        numberParts.push_back(stoi(number.substr(start, end - start)));
        end = start;
        start -= 3;
    }

    for (int i = numberParts.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int part = numberParts[i];
        if (part >= 100) {
            result += numberWords[part / 100];
            result += L" ";
            result += numberWords[100];
            part = part % 100;
            if (part > 0) {
                result += L" ";
            }
        }
        if (part >= 20) 
        {
            result += numberWords[(part / 10) * 10];
            part = part % 10;
            if (part > 0) {
                result += L" ";
                result += numberWords[part];
            }
        }
        else if (part > 0) 
        {
            result += numberWords[part];
    

}
    if (i > 0) 
    {
        result += L" ";
        if (part > 0) 
        {
            result += numberWords[1000 * (int)pow(10, i)];
            result += L"en";
        }
    }
}
return result;
```

}

Comment: Sounds like a job for debugger.

Comment: Have you run this code in your debugger?  Or are you asking us to run your code in a debugger?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: *"instead it returns 'nulleins' ('zero one')"* -- it returned just "eins" for me. Which is what it looks like the code is designed to do. Maybe you should explain how the code is supposed to work instead of leaving us to infer from the code? (If you think the explanation would run long, you're right. So try narrowing down the problem first, giving you less code to explain.)

Comment: Why `start = size - 3`? I'm always suspicious of magic numbers in code, why 3, why not 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop is incorrect

```
std::vector<int> numberParts;
int size = number.size();
int start = size - 3;
int end = size;
while (start >= 0) 
{
    if (start == 0 && size % 3 != 0) 
    {
        numberParts.push_back(stoi(number.substr(0, end - start)));
        break;
    }
    numberParts.push_back(stoi(number.substr(start, end - start)));
    end = start;
    start -= 3;
}
```

It should be something like

```
std::vector<int> numberParts;
int size = number.size();
int start = size - 3;
int end = size;
while (start > 3) 
{
    numberParts.push_back(stoi(number.substr(start, end - start)));
    end = start;
    start -= 3;
}
numberParts.push_back(stoi(number.substr(0, end - start)));
```

My version is completely untested code, but if you look at your version with `number` as "1001" you are only going round the initial loop once, consequently you only get one entry in `numberParts`.

Using a debugger would have shown you the problem very quickly, as would being able to 'run' the code accurately in your head (i.e. being able to see what the code you wrote actually does instead of what you hope it does). Both are essential skills for a programmer.